# Is it possible to make a constant not changeable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm having trouble to understand:

```
1.9.3p448 :004 > a = {a: 1, b: 2}
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
1.9.3p448 :005 > b = a
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
1.9.3p448 :006 > b[:c] = 3
 => 3 
1.9.3p448 :007 > a
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} 
1.9.3p448 :008 >
```

I don't understand why `a` changes. 
Want only to change `b` and keep `a` with its original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Looking at the question again, it came to me why this is happening in the first place:
You are actually only assigning a reference to your local variable. Changing the values locally also changes the values inside the original hash then. You might want to try `.dup` to get a copy of the values.
It is only a shallow copy though, so depending on the objects you may have in there, it may not fully work.

Original:

You can use `freeze` to keep it from being changed. If a change is applied, a RuntimeError will be thrown. It's still no 100% protection but it'll keep accidental changes from happening.

```
CONSTANT = {:key1 => 'some value', :key2 => 'some other value'}.freeze
```

See the docs here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze

And a rant with limitations here:
http://m.onkey.org/ruby-i-don-t-like-3-object-freeze

Comment: Yep you're right. `dup` solved it. However the problem still seems strange to me.

Comment: Note that `freeze` is also shallow, so prevents mods to the primary object but not to references to contained objects. `h={a:1,b:2,c:[1,2]}.freeze; h2=h` `h2[:a] = 11` or `h2[:d] = 4` will raise `RuntimeError`, but `h2[:c] << 4` will modify the referenced array: => `{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[1, 2, 4]}`